# Parser expression for comma-separated function call parameters

Tags: parsing, function, optional-parameters, bnf, lemon

Im writing a parser than can parse expressions like `myfunc1()`, `myfunc2(param1)` and `myfunc3(param1, param2)` (with an unknown amount of parameters). Now I'm trying to get my parse expressions right. I'm using the [Lemon Parser Generator](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/lemon.html). Here is what I've come up with:

```
application(res) ::= APPLICATIONNAME(a) BRACE_OPEN params BRACE_CLOSE. {res = a;}
application(res) ::= APPLICATIONNAME(a) BRACE_OPEN BRACE_CLOSE. {res = a;}
params ::= PARAM(p). {res = p;}
params ::= SEPARATOR.
```

Never mind the contents of the curly braces for the moment. The `params` definition allows empty params (several separators after each other), which is ok at the moment. But how would I have to change the definition to force non-empty parameters but still have all parameters separated by the `SEPARATOR` token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following the example from http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/lemon.html which reads

```
list ::= list element.      // left-recursion.  Good!
list ::= .
```

where `list` is either empty (the second rule) or contains at least one `element`, with individual `element` s separated by whitespace, i'd say you want

```
params ::= params SEPARATOR PARAM(p).
params ::= PARAM(p).
```

Comment: If I'd like to allow empty params, would I add the line params ::= SEPARATOR ?